# Pandas Dataframe from "messy" list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataset

I have a list of lists of data that have values and titles mixed up. This is an example of the list:

```
[{'id': 1132020, 'from': 1607472600, 'at': 1607472660024394207, 'to': 1607472660, 'open': 1.21094, 'close': 1.21096, 'min': 1.21093, 'max': 1.21097, 'volume': 18}, {'id': 1160021, 'from': 1607472660, 'at': 1607472720024366554, 'to': 1607472720, 'open': 1.21096, 'close': 1.21097, 'min': 1.21094, 'max': 1.21097, 'volume': 9}]
```

However, I want to create a Pandas Dataset with this information. I have tried to do what was described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418234/14790671, but was unable to successfully get the dataset. Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Did you try pd.DataFrame(<your_list?)?

Comment: Why it is messy. I am able to create dataframe with the two rows provided

Comment: Maybe post current incorrect df and expected df output. Or if getting an error in trying to make the df post the error. It is unclear what you mean by unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do the thing you want. Check each line so you can understand the code and know "how to" in the future. Better use a console to see the results at the same time. (I use Pycharm console for that, it's really helpful)

```
import pandas as pd

lst_of_dicts = [{'id': 1132020, 'from': 1607472600, 'at': 1607472660024394207, 'to': 1607472660, 'open': 1.21094, 'close': 1.21096, 'min': 1.21093, 'max': 1.21097, 'volume': 18}, {'id': 1160021, 'from': 1607472660, 'at': 1607472720024366554, 'to': 1607472720, 'open': 1.21096, 'close': 1.21097, 'min': 1.21094, 'max': 1.21097, 'volume': 9}]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst_od_dicts)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked great.